# Gnuplot: horizontal key ordering (transpose)

Tags: key, gnuplot, legend

I have a plot with 9 lines, and a 3x3 key. My plot command involves a loop as I need to plot from various data files in a particular order. The default key settings seem to stack the line titles vertically, how can I change this to horizontal ordering (or transpose of the key)? i.e. the key currently is displayed like:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

and I would like:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

MWE below, I would prefer to reorder the key than the actual plot loop.:

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced size 17cm,13.125cm colour 18 "Helvetica"

set output 'MWETransposeKey.eps'

set xrange [0:1]
set xtics 1
set yrange [-1:1.5]
set ytics 1
set key top left box horizontal maxcols 3 width 2 spacing 1.5

# number of curves:
N=9.0
## sine function:
f(x,n)=sin((x-0.5*(n-1)/N)*(2*pi))

plot for [n=1:N] f(x,n) w l title sprintf("Line %d",n)
```

[Key order is stacked vertically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcJe7.png)

I have already tried the invert keyword, but then the key becomes:

```
3 6 9
2 5 8
1 4 7
```

[Inverted key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUOFM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amended answer:

It should be `set key horizontal` but as you point out it doesn't behave the way you want.  Let's call that either a bug or a missing feature.

Work-around:

Although it is cumbersome, it is possible to construct the key by hand in any order you like using the `keyentry` feature of the plot command.

```
plot for [n=1:N] f(x,n) w l notitle, \
     for [n in "1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9"] keyentry title sprintf("Line %d",int(n))
```

[image]

Comment: I have set key horizontal in the MWE. It seems to work if there is only one row, but for the multi-row, multi-column format I have chosen, the key always defaults to vertical ordering.

Comment: Ah, my mistake.  Yes I think you have found a bug.  I will retract my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Ethan's manual `keyentry` solution which will always work, here is an automated version in case you have a datafile with headers which you don't want to copy or re-type again.
This workaround simply transposes the keys.

**Code:**

```
### workaround for transposing the order of the keyentries
reset session

$Data <<EOD
A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I     J     K     L
1.05  1.10  1.15  1.20  1.25  1.30  1.35  1.40  1.45  1.50  1.55  1.60
1.05  1.10  1.15  1.20  1.25  1.30  1.35  1.40  1.45  1.50  1.55  1.60
2.05  2.10  2.15  2.20  2.25  2.30  2.35  2.40  2.45  2.50  2.55  2.60
EOD

myMaxRow = 3
myMaxCol = 4

row(i) = (i-1)%myMaxRow
col(i) = (i-1)/myMaxRow   # here gnuplot's integer divison is desired
KeyTranspose(i) = row(i)*myMaxCol + col(i) +1

set key top left vertical maxrow myMaxRow maxcol myMaxCol

plot for [i=1:12] $Data u 0:i w lp ps 1.5 pt i lc i notitle, \
     for [i=1:12] $Data u (NaN) w lp ps 1.5 pt KeyTranspose(i) lc KeyTranspose(i) title columnhead(KeyTranspose(i))
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: oops, I just noticed that this will only work correctly if you have exactly 12 datasets (or in general `myMaxRow` x `myMaxCol` datasets). I will try to fix this.